# I need to change a wp plugin to choose another taxonomy according to the page that i use it

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am using the post-grid-and-filter-ultimate plugin to create some filters.
I am also using a plugin to create custom taxonomies.

I have created 5 different blog pages where i need to display different filters

- 1st page is using the taxonomy vegan which have filters burger, pizza etc
- 2nd page is using taxonomy vegetarian which have filters burger, pizza etc
- and so on.

I would like the plugin to read different taxonomy for every page.

This one here

```
if( !defined( 'PGAFU_CAT' ) ) {
    define( 'PGAFU_CAT', 'vegan_dish' ); 
}
```

defines the category/taxonomy.

For blogpage with title "vegan places" it should read the taxonomy "vegan_dish". For blog page with title "vegetarian places" it skould read the taxonomy "vegetarian_dish" and so on.

I believe that this could be done with a "for" but dont know how to let it read the page titles/ids of wordpress

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you make a raw [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) you'll receive lots of metadata for the current post/page. You could analyze the slug or match the title or whatnot. There are lots of ways to do this, but be aware that building logic on top of "some string" is always a bit risky.

Comment: Thanks flomei! 
Will this run for everypage where the shortcode of the plugin is being put? (sorry i forgot to mention that i use the plugin with its shortcode)

Comment: Well. that depends on how you integrate it. But if it's in your theme files like page.php it will run for every page for example, yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Hi again tried this code:
`$post = get_post(); 
if( !defined( 'PGAFU_CAT' ) ) {
if($post->ID == 588) { define( 'PGAFU_CAT', 'vegan_dish' );
}
else if($post->ID == 650) { define( 'PGAFU_CAT', 'vegetarian_dish' );
}
else if($post->ID == 667)
{
 define( 'PGAFU_CAT', 'gf_dish' );
}
else if($post->ID == 670)
{
 define( 'PGAFU_CAT', 'lf_dish' );
}
else if($post->ID == 661)
{
 define( 'PGAFU_CAT', 'diabetics_dish' );
}
 
}` 
it doesnt work.. i put the shortcode to the page from page editor (backend of WP),not .php file I guess,the code cant read the page in which the shortcode is